# How to run a query on Array of object?

Tags: arrays, haxe

I often find my self trying to calculate closest point in an Array of points, or lowest Sprite in array of sprites .. etc

For example: to calculate the lowest point in an Array:

```
var lowestPoint:Point;
var lowestY:Float= Math.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
for (point in points)
    if (point.y < lowestY)
    {
        lowestPoint= point;
        lowestY.y= point.y;
    }
```

So, isn't there better way to calculate this? may be a library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is: Why are you writing this often? 
If the real problem is that you don't want to rewrite the same code over and over, use a function.

If you're just looking for a more simple way to write this, try using `Lambda.fold`, you can read how it works [Here](http://old.haxe.org/api/lambda/fold/examples)

This will find the lowest point in points.
Note that it does make the assumption that at least one point is in the array.

```haxe
var lowest = Lambda.fold(points, function(a, b) { return if (a.y < b.y) a else b; }, points[0])
```

The combination of using `Lambda.map`, `Lambda.filter`, and `Lambda.reduce` will provide you with a powerful query interface, but remember that implementing your function with a for loop will provide better performance than by using Lambda.fold.

You could clean up for loop code by doing:

```
var lowestPoint:Point = points[0];
for (point in points)
  if (point.y < lowestPoint.y)
  {
    lowestPoint = point;
  }
```

(again, this assumes that there is at least one point in points)